# trouble with pysphere - ansible

Tags: module, automation, ansible, vmware

i am trying to deploy a VM via Ansible on my ESXi host. 
I am using the following role for this:

```
- vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.****.net
    username: ****
    password: ****
    guest: newvm001
    state: powered_off
    vm_extra_config:
      vcpu.hotadd: yes
      mem.hotadd:  yes
      notes: This is a test VM
    vm_disk:
      disk1:
        size_gb: 10
        type: thin
        datastore: ****
    vm_nic:
      nic1:
        type: vmxnet3
        network: VM Network
        network_type: standard
    vm_hardware:
      memory_mb: 4096
      num_cpus: 4
      osid: windows7Server64Guest
      scsi: paravirtual
    esxi:
      datacenter: MyDatacenter
      hostname: esx-s18t.****.net
```

when i execute this role now via a playbook i get the following message:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook -i Inventory vmware_deploy.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.20.22.5]

TASK [vmware : vsphere_guest] **************************************************
fatal: [172.20.22.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "pysphere module required"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.20.22.5                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

So it seems to be "pysphere" module is missing. i've already checked that with the command:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# pip install pysphere
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysphere in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysphere-0                          .1.7-py2.7.egg
```

Then i did the "upgrade" and get the following message back:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# pip install pysphere --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: pysphere in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysphere-0.1.7-py2.7.egg
```

So it seems to be it is already installed and its up-to-date , why do i get this error message then?
How can i fix it that my god damn role works fine now?
Jesus, Ansible makes me crazy ..

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!

kind regards,
kgierman

EDIT:
so i've writen a new playbook with the old stuff, the new playbool lookes like this(i've added your localhost and connection local stuff):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.****.net
            username: ****
            password: ****
            guest: newvm001
            state: powered_off
        vm_extra_config:
            vcpu.hotadd: yes
            mem.hotadd:  yes
            notes: This is a test VM
        vm_disk:
            disk1:
            size_gb: 10
            type: thin
            datastore: ****
        vm_nic:
            nic1:
            type: vmxnet3
            network: VM Network
            network_type: standard
        vm_hardware:
            memory_mb: 4096
            num_cpus: 4
            osid: windows7Server64Guest
            scsi: paravirtual
        esxi:
            datacenter: MyDatacenter
            hostname: esx-s18t.****.net
```

so when i execute this playbook i get the following error:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook vmware2.yml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/vmware2.yml': line 7, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
          username: root
                  ^ here
```

the struggle is real -.-

Answer (score 0):

You generally should execute provisioning modules such as `vsphere_guest` on your local ansible machine.
I suspect that `172.20.22.5` is actually your ESX host, and ansible try to execute module from there, where pysphere is surely absent.
Use:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
         ...
```

Comment: yep ypu're right, the 172.20.22.5 is the ESXi host, but if i want to deploy a VM there (cause there is the VCenter & stuff) - but the OS on the ESXi is something else then Ubuntu , so how can i still create a VM via Ansible on VSphere?

Comment: You specify it as `vcenter_hostname` param – ansible module will connect to it _from localhost_ and create requested VMs.

Comment: sorry i dont get it what you mean with this :/ 
"You specify it as vcenter_hostname param" , can you give me an example?

Comment: In your example playbook ansible will connect to `emea-esx-s18t.****.net` with user `****` and password `****` and create VM `newvm001`. You just need to call this task on localhost, not on ESX host itself.

Comment: so you mean i need to it like this:

Comment: so you mean i need to it like this?:
`---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
            username: root`

Comment: i guess you just need `hosts: localhost` and `connection: local`, everything else leave as you have now.

Comment: i've editet my main question above, cause i've get an error when i try to to this playbook -.-
maybe you know a solution for it?

Comment: there is a dash missing before `vsphere_guest:` – should be `- vsphere_guest:`

Comment: jesus christ, now i am getting another error -.- now it says "'vsphere_guest' is not a valid attribute for a Play" what the hell is going on here !
so this topic is quite long, is there any other possibility to stay in contact with you ?
like e-mail or stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue once again on macOS / OSX...
It seems to be related to `PYTHONPATH`.

I have this in my `.profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

[ ... further down ... ]

export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.1.2.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.1.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

The first line with `PYTHONPATH` is where `pysphere` and other system modules reside.
Also take note of the **specific version** of Ansible!
Anyway, this seems to resolve the issue.

Source: https://github.com/debops/debops-tools/issues/159#issuecomment-236536195