# Trying to deploy a VM on ESXi with Ansible

Tags: ansible

In a playbook i've written the following lines:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
- vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
    username: root
    password: HWL-sddc
    guest: newvm001
    state: powered_off
    vm_extra_config:
      vcpu.hotadd: yes
      mem.hotadd:  yes
      notes: This is a test VM
    vm_disk:
      disk1:
        size_gb: 10
        type: thin
        datastore: gmh-040-data-esx-sddc
    vm_nic:
      nic1:
        type: vmxnet3
        network: VM Network
        network_type: standard
    vm_hardware:
      memory_mb: 4096
      num_cpus: 4
      osid: windows7Server64Guest
      scsi: paravirtual
    esxi:
      datacenter: MyDatacenter
      hostname: esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
```

When I execute the playbook i'm getting the following message back:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook vmware2.yml
ERROR! 'vsphere_guest' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/vmware2.yml': line 5, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
- vsphere_guest:
  ^ here
```

I already asked this question in the past -> [trouble with pysphere - ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736888/trouble-with-pysphere-ansible)

It seems to be that the ESXi doesn't know the module or the command.

Comment: Oh, man... why don't you read error messages? and YAML basics? The indentation of `- vsphere_guest:` is wrong – move the whole block under `tasks:`.

Comment: i'm able to read. no worries ;)
i already did this and get the same error message again... thats why i'm asking. 
I am so sorry that i am not a programmer ;)
thats why i'm asking here mate, to get some help if it is possible,..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
        username: root
        password: HWL-sddc
        guest: newvm001
        state: powered_off
        vm_extra_config:
          vcpu.hotadd: yes
          mem.hotadd:  yes
          notes: This is a test VM
        vm_disk:
          disk1:
            size_gb: 10
            type: thin
            datastore: gmh-040-data-esx-sddc
        vm_nic:
          nic1:
            type: vmxnet3
            network: VM Network
            network_type: standard
        vm_hardware:
          memory_mb: 4096
          num_cpus: 4
          osid: windows7Server64Guest
          scsi: paravirtual
        esxi:
          datacenter: MyDatacenter
          hostname: esx-s18t.sddc-hwl-family.net
```

Comment: This works, but now i'm getting another error message ..
' root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook vmware2.yml

`....
TASK [vsphere_guest] ***********************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "parsed": false}
....`
So why i'm getting this? i got an SSL Certificate

Comment: Try `validate_certs: no`, http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html

Comment: i've added it before the line "vcenter_hostname:.." and i am getting now the error `TASK [vsphere_guest] ***********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: validate_certs"}
`